# Auction House in Neverwinter

Tags: neverwinter

This is probably a stupid question; I'm finding answers all over google but nothing telling me this though:

*Where* is the auction house?

I find links on the economy, how to make a fortune with astral diamonds, how to buy/sell... but I cannot find the bloody place in the game.
Any help would be appreciated.
(Note: I'm level 15; I got to the 20's a few years back but quit playing and started over. So I have access to the basic areas. I'm f2p, if that matters.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Neverwinter Auction House is the Tamalune Auction house, which can be found in the Protector's Enclave, between the Moonstone Mask (the floating brothel) and the Seven Suns Coster Market.

The below image marks the Auction House in blue on the map.

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU! I was mouse-overing so much but I guess I totally missed this. I appreciate you stating the answer and not downvoting me because I am blind as a bat.